# UWP/WinRT: How to perform a UI task upon completion of an asynchronous operation in a model?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, mvvm, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I'm following the MVVM pattern, and have a model called a `DocumentStore`. The class has a method as follows:

```
void DocumentStore::Open_Document(StorageFile^ file) {
    create_task(FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file))
        .then([this, file](String^ fileContents)
    {
        // Take the fileContents and add them to internal data structure
    });
}
```

My ViewModel is popping up a `FileOpenPicker` to get a file that it then feed as the argument into `Open_Document`:

```
create_task(picker->PickSingleFileAsync())
    .then([this](StorageFile^ file) 
    {
        m_DocStore->Open_Document(file); 
        // Target location to do something
    }
);
```

I'd like to be able to perform an action after the task inside of `Open_Document` has completed, i.e. after the fileContents have been processed.

Is there a way for my Model to notify any interested listeners that a task is complete?

Or should my Model's `Open_Document` method actually be itself asynchronous? However, I need to process the data structure inside the task, and wouldn't that cause my method to be running inside a different thread context?

I'm working in C++/CX but will take any help I can get.

Comment: Have you considered passing a lambda to `OpenDocument` that can be called when the asynchronous work has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the process will be as following.

Open the file -> Read the content -> process the content -> do STH else.

You can push the async operation to the task chain and create a new async operation by using create_async method.

Here is the code for your reference:

```
create_task(StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/XMLFile.xml")))
.then([](StorageFile^ file) {
    WriteLine("Read the file");
    return FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file);
}).then([](task<String^> task) {
    String ^ text = task.get();
    WriteLine("Content: " + text);
    return create_async([text]() {
        WriteLine("Process the text: " + text);
    });
}).then([](task<void> task) {
    task.get();

    WriteLine("Do STH else");
});
```

Comment: In my situation, the read the file and process the text steps are happening in another class, a Model. The ViewModel would want to perform a task after the processing of the text is complete (for example, opening a dialog informing the user what was found inside the text). I believe that would be analogous to in your current code of getting "Do STH else" to execute only after "Process the text:" completes. If I'm not mistaken, in your current code, "Do STH else" could happen before "Process the text:" since the return create_async returns immediately, right?

Comment: No, the "Do STH else" would happen after "process the text", I used the task.get() to ensure it.

Comment: Ah, thank you, didn't realize that. So do you have any ideas how this could be made to fit code that separates the Model from the ViewModel? I updated the question with sample code from the ViewModel to make discussion easier. The calling code in the ViewModel won't have access to the task object to call task.get(), at least not directly. I could have Open_Document in the model return the task object, though that strikes me as breaking the spirit of the MVVM model. What do you think, what's the proper way to code this interaction?

Comment: Minor code nit: you don't need the `task<void>` param in the final continuation - the main reason for accepting a task is so that you can detect errors, but since you blindly call `get` it's going to throw anyway. So if you're confident that no exceptions will be propagated, just do away with the task<> altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting what I ended up going with, but I accepted Jeffrey Chen's answer since it helped me get there.

My Model now has an Event `DocOpened`. This is fired upon completion of `Open_Document`. I subscribed my ViewModel to this Event with a handler that is capable of performing tasks whenever that Event is fired.